# MYSQL - Trigger: IF Date is null, set date to CURDATE INTERVAL 1 DAY

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

Trying to build a simple trigger that modifies the MYSQL database in the following manner AFTER a new record is inserted in the TABLE:

Psudo code:

```
IF TABLE.AssignedDate IS NULL THEN
Set TABLE.DueDate = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1
ELSE 
SET TABLE.DueDate = AssignedDate + INTERVAL 1
```

I'm pretty sure I can't force the TIMESTAMP item from AssignedDate into the Interval 1 scenario. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use date_add

```
Set TABLE.DueDate = date_add(CURDATE(),  INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This does work for the trigger. Inevitably, I just worked the code into the PHP function to check prior to the data being committed to the database. But this solution did work for anyone interested.